# VBA Excel conditional based page break when new values are added

Tags: excel, vba

I have the document with over 900 rows.
I set the one-page break including just the first 47 of them.
However when some new rows will be filled (every 48th one exactly) I would like to expand this page preview by another 47 rows and so forth.

[image]

So far my code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
                .PrintArea = "A1:V47"
                .FitToPagesWide = 1
                .FitToPagesTall = False
                '
End With


 If ActiveSheet.Rows(53).Len(vValue & vbNullString) > 0 Then
 ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:V97"
 ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Rows(48)
 End If

 End Sub
```

But it doesn't work well as a method such as this is not supported.

Is there any way to set the conditional-based page break like this?

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look this link : https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1774-excel-insert-page-break-every-row.html

Comment: It's a good hint, but I need something value-based instead of defining the row manually

Comment: I thought that you want the page break every 48th rows depend on the last row of data ? For example there are 150 rows of data (so, the last row number is 150). Modify a bit the code in the link, you end up with 4 section of page break ---> The first until the third consist 48 rows, the fourth consist 6 rows. Next time the data grows for example until 300 rows, the result gives you 7 page. The first 6 pages consist 48 rows, the 7th page consist 12 rows. So, what did you mean "value based" ? Please CMIIW.

Comment: I don't know how to start to modify the link, to be honest. I would lie to have a page break initially at row 47, but if I put anything in row 53 I would lie to have this page break expanded to row 96 with HPageBreaks at row 47... Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure if I understand you correctly.

Anyway, the code below will create a page break (where each page will always consist of 5 rows, don't care how many rows of data are there within those 5 rows) only IF the last row with data is > 5 and also create a print area.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r As Integer: r = 5 'change if needed
Dim pa As String: pa = "A1:C" 'change if needed
Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ActiveSheet
Dim LR As Integer: LR = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If LR Mod r <> 0 Then LR = LR + (r - LR Mod r)
sh.PageSetup.PrintArea = pa & LR

sh.ResetAllPageBreaks
For i = r + 1 To LR Step r: sh.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=sh.Cells(i, 1): Next

End Sub
```

r is the count of rows consist in each page.
pa is the print area, starting from A1 to column C whatever row of the last row of data.
LR is the last row of data on the sheet column A.

It check if LR mod r <> 0 then it add r - LR mod r to LR value in order to have LR value mod 5 always 0.

Example :
r = 5. 
the last row with data in column A is 7, so ... LR = 7.
The result of 7 mod 5 is 2 (the remainder) ---> because the mod result is not zero, then it make LR value with 7 + 5 - 2 ---> now LR value is 10. Then it make the print area range A1:C10, then it loop to add a page break with 5 rows for each page.

[image]